# Xcode4: with categories: ... Class method ... not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I keep getting this for situations that are patently false, related to objective-c categories.

NB: this was working fine, then stopped working overnight.

It's as if Xcode is fundamentally broken in it's ability to "read the file system", and it's driving me nuts. Any ideas on how to force it to ... read the file system ... would be appreciated.

e.g.:

1. Start Xcode, write a file, import it, using Xcode autocomplete.
2. cmd-click on the import line, and it jumps to the header file
3. A few builds later, Xcode flags a Warning:, e.g. "Class method '+stringFromCGPath:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')"
4. Now when you cmd-click on the import line, Xcode flashes up a dialog "Symbol not found" (world's worst dialog box? doesn't even have a confirm, it flashes and vanishes)
5. If you run the app, it crashes on that line, saying the selector not recognized

Then, to prove how FUBAR Xcode is:

1. Quit Xcode, restart
2. Cmd-click is working again
3. ...but the Warning is still in place, and the app still crashes
4. After a few seconds, cmd-click stops working

NB: things I've checked:

1. The file is in the project folder? YES
2. The .m file is included in the Target? YES
3. The .m file is in the list of files to compile? YES
4. Do a CLEAN ... then a BUILD? YES

---

UPDATE: an example header I'm trying to import - that I have been successfully importing for months, and worked fine in hundreds of builds, and I have NOT changed (confirmed using SCM):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "CGGeometryExtensions.h"

@interface NSString(CGPath)

+(NSString*) NSStringFromCGPath:(CGPathRef) path;

@end
```

---

UPDATE2: actually, this doesn't crash at runtime - it was crashing because there was a typo in the call to "NSStringFromCGPath:" (one letter was lower case when it should have been upper case). But this was hard to see because of XCode's claim that the whole header file didn't exist - even though, as noted above, the IMPORT line was auto-generated by Xcode.

Comment: Please report this to Apple at https://bugreport.apple.com especially if you have a repeatable test case.

Comment: Seems odd to have that as a category on NSString;  since CG* is a functional API, I would suggest creating a set of utility functions that do this, instead.   I.e. `NSString *MyNSStringFromCGPath();` -- always use a prefix to prevent collision.

Comment: @bbum tell that to Apple :) they decided to put all these class of methods into NSString, even though it's 1) not extensible (except in this manner) and 2) many developers never discover these methods exist

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you may have problems with the indexer. Have you got multiple targets in your project, or multiple projects in a workspace? If so, make sure they **all** build completely cleanly - a failure indexing one target can mess up code completion on another.

You might also try deleting your project's **DerivedData** folder

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific: no, only one target, only one project, and I tried deleting all build folders. No dice :(